# How to debug typescript in meteor

Tags: debugging, meteor, typescript

Using Webstrom I can debug normal serverside and clientside javascrpt of the meteor app.
But how I can do debuging in case of typescript?

I just run meteor typescript sample from here https://github.com/meteor-typescript/meteor-typescript-compiler

I just set a breakpoint with debug session in the code:
[image]

But nothing happend. The break point hasne being hit.

To compile typescript I am using `meteor add meteortypescript:compiler` so it is done automatically when meteor app starts.

That is the `js` output I've got:

```
(function(){

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                                                     //
// helloWorld.js                                                       //
//                                                                     //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                                                                       //
'use strict';                                                          // 1
var HelloWorld = (function () {                                        // 3
    function HelloWorld(name) {                                        //
        if (name === void 0) { name = 'World'; }                       //
        this.name = name;                                              //
    }                                                                  //
    HelloWorld.prototype.toString = function () {                      //
        return "Hello " + this.name;                                   //
    };                                                                 //
    return HelloWorld;                                                 //
})();                                                                  // 9
console.log(new HelloWorld().toString());                              // 11
//# sourceMappingURL=helloWorld.js.map                                 //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

}).call(this);
```

My `.tsconfig` config:

```
{
  "diagnostics": true,
  "module": "none",
  "alwaysThrow": true,
  "noResolve": true,
  "useCache": false,
  "sourceMap": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sourceMap` needs to be true in your `.tsconfig` : https://github.com/meteor-typescript/meteor-typescript-compiler#tsconfig

Comment: Just put it in. Can't see any difference.